# why apache cordova keep Polling and XHR two ways to fetch data?

Tags: cordova

when i read the source code of apache cordova. i find it has two ways to fecth the callback data from native code?

why the author did'nt keep polling only?

are there some issues exist?

Thanks for your anwser!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about Apache Cordova Android version. Since we need to asynchronously communicate between the JavaScript and native layers we use XHR so that when the result is ready on the native side we execute the success callback. This method works well in most all cases.

However, if the device happens to have a proxy setup then that's where we get into issues. With the proxy in between the JS and native layer the XHR fails. In that case we default back to polling. This is a more wasteful way of getting the result.